# How to allow jetty server status info for only localhost

Tags: jetty

Apache can let this configuration with these codes

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from my-ip-address:no-port#
</Location>

<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from my-ip-address-no-port
</Location>
```

How can I do that in Jetty ? 
For example, in *jetty-http.xml* , this code disable to see server version

```
<Set name="sendServerVersion">false</Set>
```

Jetty version is

> 9.2.15.v20160210

Comment: Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life), consider using something up to date and stable. - see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Comment: Is there anyway to define this config in version 9.4 ?